# Function does not even get called when yield is used to return values in python

Tags: python, yield

I am scraping weather data using scrapy and selenium from the WunderGround website. When I am using yield to return a list of data for a day, that function does not even get called. I am providing part of my code which returns the data

```
 def datarecords(self,month=None,year=None,num_of_years=1):
    ''' return the available months and years in the website and find out datas for the last 1 year if not mentioned otherwise'''

    try:

        if month is None and year is None:
            ''' take the months in _months to loop and find the data for every
            month'''
            #print("in database if")
            for year in range(self.years[0]-num_of_years,self.years[0]):
                for month in self.months:
                    self._monthyear(month,year)
                    sleep(5)
                    self.current_record(month,year)

        else:
            self.logger.info(f"*****************in else statement of datarecords method for scraping the {month} in {year}****************")
            #self._monthyear(month,year)
            #sleep(5)
            self.current_record(month,year)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error in datarecords method:{} and closing the browser".format(e))
        self.browser.close()

def current_record(self,month,year):
    self.logger.info('*********************in current record*************************')


    #return currently available records to the date of the given month and year

    self._monthyear(month,year)
    self.logger.info("****************** in current record method again*****************")
    month_number = (dt.strptime(month,'%B')).month
    print(month_number,type(month_number),year,type(year))
    sleep (5)
    try:
        print("in try")
        table_cols = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//table[@class="days ng-star-inserted"]/tbody/tr/td')
        print(len(table_cols))
        total_major_cols = len(table_cols)

        num_of_days = len(self._rowlength(table_cols[0])) #find number of rows in each cols which also corresponds to the number of days

        print(f"number of days in current month: ",num_of_days)
        for day in range(1,num_of_days):
            print("time now",dt.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            row_entries = [] # keep the record of each row
            for cols in range(0,total_major_cols):
                ''' loop through each cols to extract the data'''
                rows = table_cols[cols].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'tr')
                data = self._findvalue(rows[day])
                row_entries += data


            row_entries[0] = dt.date(int(year),month_number,int(row_entries[0]))

            #self._daily_weather_data = WeatherRec._make(row_entries)
            yield {'Date':row_entries[0],
                   'Max_Temp':row_entries[1],'Avg_Temp':row_entries[2],'Min_Temp':row_entries[3],
                   'Max_Dew_Point':row_entries[4],'Avg_Dew_Point':row_entries[5],'Min_Dew_Point':row_entries[6],
                   'Max_Humidity':row_entries[7],'Avg_Humidity':row_entries[8],'Min_Humidity':row_entries[9],
                   'Max_Wind_Speed_mph':row_entries[10],'Avg_Wind_Speed_mph':row_entries[11],'Min_Wind_Speed_mph':row_entries[12],
                   'Max_Pressure_Hg':row_entries[13],'Avg_Pressure_Hg':row_entries[14],'Min_Pressure_Hg':row_entries[15],
                   'Precipitation_in':row_entries[16]
                }`
```

Here row_entries is the data for one day. I want to return it using yield so that I can call scrapy crawl spider -o  data.csv at the same time. But when I use 'yield' the method current record does not even get called. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Create a [mre] please.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  When you call `self.current_record()`, you get a generator.  You have to do something with it in order to have it give you values.

Comment: But, the print statements in the self.current_record() are not even showing when I use yield. I tried to extract the data directly into CSV as shown in this tutorial [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-minimalist-end-to-end-scrapy-tutorial-part-i-11e350bcdec0)